# Stopping a OpenFileDialog with a button

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a media player that i have made as part of a school project. I have a button that when pressed hides the form and shows another. What i want to do is have the button also stop the media file from playing. this is my code

```
Private Sub TxtName_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        e.Cancel = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnBrowse.Click
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .Title = "File Browser"
            .Filter = "Media Files (*.wmv;*.mp3)|*.wmv;*.mp3"
            .FileName = ""
            .CheckFileExists = True
        End With
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = _
            Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = _
            OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnBack.Click
        Me.Hide()
        ECoach.Show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Start/Stop... you have to use `MediaPlayerCtrl.Ctlcontrols.OrderYouWish`. That is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnBack.Click
     AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop()
     Me.Hide()
     ECoach.Show()
 End Sub
```